# How to run MySql in xampp server?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, server

How to solve this problem ?

I want to connection mysql server with php code. But I try run mysql database service, I see this error.

```
17:45:11  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped 17:45:11  [mysql]
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. 17:45:11  [mysql]    This may be
due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,  17:45:11  [mysql]
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

17:45:11  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

17:45:11  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 17:45:11 
[mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this 17:45:11  [mysql]
entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Have you done as the message told you? `Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 17:45:11 [mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should check that your MySQL port is not occupied, such as 3306

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of things-

Try running mysql console and see if mysql is working fine or not. If so, try connecting it to php and execute your code

Run xampp as administartor and then try running mysql